# Check if any of the following siblings have a specified name

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

The structure of my xml document is as follows. I need to know at element field name = "a" if any of its following siblings have the element name *repeatingGroup*

```
<messages>
   <field name = "a">
      <text value = "Cover/>
   </field>          
   <field name = "b">
      <text value = "price"/>
   </field>
   <repeatingGroup>
      <field name = "c"/>
      <field name = "d"/>
   </repeatingGroup>
</messages>
```

The code segment I tried so far only  provided the immediate sibling name. In this case field name = "b". Is there a way to check if any of the following siblings have the specified name without using a foreach block? My requirement is to print a value if the condition is true

```
<xsl:if test="name(following-sibling::*)='repeatingGroup'"></xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Use

```
 <xsl:if test="following-sibling::repeatingGroup">
   <!-- Your Condition -->
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Will the same condition hold true in a case where there are multiple repeatingGroup blocks and the requirement is to check if any of the repeatingGroup blocks have a  field element with a nested text element?

Comment: if you want to check only repeatingGroup than this condition hold true, for matching exact condition you can edit this for only matches child field<xsl:if test="following-sibling::repeatingGroup[field]"> and only matches child field with subchild text <xsl:if test="following-sibling::repeatingGroup[field[text]]">